# Using font awesome over container that already has pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, pseudo-element

I need to display font awesome icons on a div that already has pseudo elements (before and after) applied. Say I have a div, a 3d effect paper, which uses pseudo elements. Now I want to draw a contact us form, which uses font awesome icons. But the font awesome icons are not displaying.

I tried to keep a dummy div around the contact us form, with clear fix. But still didn't work

**UPDATE:** http://jsfiddle.net/tss5Z/

```
<div class="slickbox row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just have an error in your CSS.

Try removing the space after your class selectors... so:

```
.slickbox :before, .slickbox :after { ...
```

would become:

```
.slickbox:before, .slickbox:after { ...
```

and so on. See working **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tss5Z/1/)**.

Comment: With the space it does not know which selector the ":before" belongs to and probably tries to apply the styles to all ":before"s inside of the element with selector ".slickbox"... when it should only apply it to ".slickbox" itself. Similarly ".class1.class2" would look for an element with both .class1 and .class2, while ".class1 .class2" looks for an element with ".class2" inside of an element with ".class1".

Comment: OOPS... This is not working when I include bootstrap.min.css. But I am using bootstrap in rest of the pages.  http://jsfiddle.net/tss5Z/2/

Comment: Bootstrap is setting all :before and :after elements to display:table... try adding display:block; to your CSS to override.